# xml to json correct conversion

Tags: javascript, json, xml

I need to read a file where the content is written in XML. I want to convert the content in JSON and then acceed to its components (sigma,type). The problem is that I have one method to convert from xml to json, but I think it is not working. The code is the next one:

```
function xmlToJson2( xml ) {
 
    // Create the return object
    var obj = {};
   
    if ( xml.nodeType == 1 ) { // element
      // do attributes
      if ( xml.attributes.length > 0 ) {
      obj["@attributes"] = {};
        for ( var j = 0; j < xml.attributes.length; j++ ) {
          var attribute = xml.attributes.item( j );
          obj["@attributes"][attribute.nodeName] = attribute.nodeValue;
        }
      }
    } else if ( xml.nodeType == 3 ) { // text
      obj = xml.nodeValue;
    }
   
    // do children
    if ( xml.hasChildNodes() ) {
      for( var i = 0; i < xml.childNodes.length; i++ ) {
        var item = xml.childNodes.item(i);
        var nodeName = item.nodeName;
        if ( typeof(obj[nodeName] ) == "undefined" ) {
          obj[nodeName] = xmlToJson2( item );
        } else {
          if ( typeof( obj[nodeName].push ) == "undefined" ) {
            var old = obj[nodeName];
            obj[nodeName] = [];
            obj[nodeName].push( old );
          }
          obj[nodeName].push( xmlToJson2( item ) );
        }
      }
    }
    return obj;
  };
```

I call that method this way

```
let reader2 = new FileReader();
                reader2.readAsText(file2);
                reader2.onloadend = (evt) => {
                    var parser = new DOMParser();
                    var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(evt.target.result,"text/xml");
                    let stored = JSON.stringify(xmlToJson2(xmlDoc));
                    this.data.type = stored[0].type;
                    this.data.sigma = stored[0].sigma;
                    this.data.states = stored[0].states;
                    this.data.stack = stored[0].stack;
                    this.data.button = button;
                    let res = filename2.split(".");
                    this.data.filename2 = res[0];
                    this.parent.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('dialog', { detail: { action: 'selection_data', data: this.data } }));
```

**evt.target.result** is the xml content as a string

I think the conversion method is not working because the json content is not how it was supposed to be. The first one is the xml and then the JSON conversion.

[image]

What can I do?

Comment: You define `stored` and set it to a string - the result of calling JSON.stringify on something.  You can't get `stored[0].type` and so on out of a string.  I think you would have better luck without the JSON.stringify there.

Comment: Your xml2json does not return json, it returns a javascript object.  Maybe that's some of the confusion.

Comment: *btw* You can use CSS selectors to fetch nodes from the XML: `this.data.type = xmlDoc.querySelector('type')?.textContent || 'default';` No need to convert it to JSON.